# Does Jackson or Gson support Annotation Processing for Android?

Tags: java, android, json, jackson, gson

does someone of you know if Jackson has a Module to support real Annotation Processing at compile time? I have found this module: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-module-afterburner/issues/2

However it seems not to work with Androids .dex bytecode format.

I have a very long Json File (30.000 lines containing 5000 Json objects and some more subobjects) I want to parse and using plain jackson annotation data binding using refelctions will take around 2 seconds in cold start ("running the first time"). If I parse the same file again with the same `ObjectMapper` from the first time it will take 400 ms.
So is there a real annotation processor that compiles at compile time to real java code to improve parsing performance?

I could also switch to gson, if gson supports annotation processing. Parsing the file with plain gson takes 1,2 seconds in cold start and ca. 700 ms parsing the same json file again (without cold start).

Parsing time under 500 ms would be awesome. 
Any suggestion would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean by "real Annotation Processing at compile time? I h"; but for faster startup, simple data-binding, [Jackson jr](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-jr) work well, is designed for Android style use case.
It does NOT require or use annotations, which removes one-time annotation read overhead that full Jackson has, but uses low-level Jackson Streaming API for efficient low-level reading/writing.